# Laravel one to one relationship. Save username from table to another table

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

TLDR: How do I create a relationship from one table to another? For example, I want changes from the user table automatically reflect on to the supplier table? Something like it's just referencing from the user table.

I have this 2 tables

```
========================
     USER table

     1. id
     2. username
     3. password
     4. name
========================
```

and

```
========================
     SUPPLIER table

     1. id
     2. username
     3. name
========================
```

Every time I add a new user, it should automatically be saved into the supplier table.  This is what I did:

```
function saveUser($postdata) {
    $newUser= new \App\UserModel;
    $newUser->email = $postdata['email'];
    $newUser->password = $postdata['password'];
    $newUser->name = $postdata['name'];
    $newUser->save();

    $this->saveSupplier($postdata['email'], $postdata['name']);
}

function saveSupplier($email, $name) {
    $newSupplier = new \App\SupplierModel;
    $newSupplier->email = $email;
    $newSupplier->name = $name;
    $newSupplier->save();
}
```

You see, it's not in a relationship right. It's just like manually saving into two tables. How do I make the Supplier table dependent on the user table? For example, everytime I make changes in the User table, it will automatically reflect on to suppliers table without having to fire an update method.

Comment: Why don't just create a new boolean field in the users table called "supplier" ? I only see redundant information in the supplier table.

Answer (score 1):

One way to achieve this would be to register and event in the boot method of your 
**User** model.

```
protected static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    static::created(function($user) {
        Supplier::create([
            'username' => $user->username  //or email or whatever you have.
            'name' => $user->name
        ]);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you might be interested in triggers. If you can create triggers you can use them to insert into `SUPPLIER` every time you insert in `USER`.

Something like:

```
CREATE TRIGGER t_reflect_changes_user_supplier
AFTER INSERT
   ON USER FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN
   -- trigger code
   INSERT INTO SUPPLIER (username,name) VALUES new.username,new.name
END;
```